# Why is "File.expand_path(...)" resolving to something different from what I expect?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I'm currently stepping through the code of the `gitlab_development_kit` gem to see how it works.

I'm currently at [this line of code](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-development-kit/blob/master/gem/bin/gdk#L4), and I've placed a debugger point above and below the line.

```
    3: require 'byebug'
    4: byebug
    5: 
=>  6: $LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__))
    7: byebug
    8: require 'gitlab_development_kit'
```

I inspect the values of `$LOAD_PATH` and `File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)`:

```
(byebug) $LOAD_PATH
["/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/rbenv.d/exec/gem-rehash", ...]

(byebug) File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)
"/Users/richiethomas/Workspace/ThreeEasyPieces/lib"
```

I type `next` to advance the debugger, and then re-check the above values:

```
(byebug) next

[2, 11] in /Users/richiethomas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/gitlab-development-kit-0.2.5/bin/gdk
    2: require 'yaml'
    3: require 'byebug'
    4: byebug
    5: 
    6: $LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__))
=>  7: byebug
    8: require 'gitlab_development_kit'
    9: 
   10: 
   11: 

(byebug) File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)
"/Users/richiethomas/Workspace/ThreeEasyPieces/lib"

(byebug) $LOAD_PATH
["/Users/richiethomas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/gitlab-development-kit-0.2.5/lib", "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/rbenv.d/exec/gem-rehash", ...]
```

If the value of `File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)` really was `"/Users/richiethomas/Workspace/ThreeEasyPieces/lib"`, then that's what I would expect to be pre-pended to `$LOAD_PATH`.  But instead, it looks like the `lib` dir from the version of the gem managed by RBENV was pre-pended instead.  What kind of devil's magic is this? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__FILE__` at the prompt does not evaluate to the same value as `__FILE__` in the file. In fact, `__FILE__` is the currently executing file, but at the interactive prompt, *there is no* currently executing file, ergo, `__FILE__` is just a placeholder.

Within IRb, `__FILE__` evaluates to `'(irb)'`, within Pry, it evaluates to `'(pry)'`, and within Byebug, it evaluates to `'(byebug)'`:

```
(byebug) __FILE__
"(byebug)"
```

Since `(byebug)` is a perfectly legal filename, `File.expand_path` will expand it using whatever the current working directory is. E.g. if the current working directory is `/a/b/c`, `File.expand_path(__FILE__)` will evaluate to `/a/b/c/(byebug)`. Ergo,

```
File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)
```

will then expand to

```
'/a/b/lib'
```